# Authentication Window on anonymous access SharePoint Server 2019 communication site

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-pages

I want to make a communication site in my SharePoint Server 2019 available for anonymous access. I made all the changes necessary for classic sites

- Allow anonymous in "Authentication Providers"
- Add read-only anonymous policy (I also tried "no policy")
- Allowed anonymous access inside site collection

I can access the site and the site opens. Halfway through the site rendering I get an authentication window. Ignoring it in a modern browser loads the site without some parts. Ignoring in IE11 gets me an HTTP500.

Inspecting the IIS Logs I found some calls to the SharePoint API that provide me with HTTP401s:

> POST /_api/SP.Utilities.SPSocialSwitch.IsFollowingFeatureEnabled/SP.Utilities.SPSocialSwitch.IsFollowingFeatureEnabled
>
> GET /_api/Site/Site $select=StatusBarLink,StatusBarText
>
> POST /_api/sphome/GetAcronymsAndColors labels=[{Text:%20%22Testsystem%22}]
>
> POST /_api/SP.Utilities.SPSocialSwitch.IsFollowingFeatureEnabled
>
> GET /_api/Site $select=StatusBarLink,StatusBarText
>
> POST /_api/contextinfo

Those seem to prevent me from accessing the whole site with an anonymous user.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to navigate around this?

Comment: hi did you fix this issue by any chance i am getting the same issue. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that disabling the feature "Following Content" did the trick for us. As we did not need it (it does not make sense with anonymous users anyways) we could stick with it.